# Kustomize HelmChartInflationGeneration with Common Chart Repo Property

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize

When using Kustomize HelmChartInflationGeneration, if all my charts reside in the same repository, is there a way I can set this in one place?

For example, given the below `kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
helmCharts:
- name: myapp-1
  repo: https://my-charts.repo.com
  version: v1.2.0
  releaseName: myapp-1
  namespace: dev
  valuesFile: myapp-1-values.yaml
- name: myapp-2
  repo: https://my-charts.repo.com
  version: v1.1.0
  releaseName: myapp-2
  namespace: dev
  valuesFile: myapp-2-values.yaml
```

is it possible to set the `repo` property by reference to a common value rather than having to duplicate it for each entry?

Comment: There is no support for "common" attributes for items in the `helmCharts` list.